# Change variable values on window.resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have some variable values change on window.resize().

I already found that you need to declare the variables outside the .resize function scope,  i then try to change their values in the function .resize scope. But this doesn't seem to work.

```
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var goPanel0, goPanel1, goPanel2, goPanel3;

        goPanel0 = 0;
        goPanel1 = windowHeight;
        goPanel2 = windowHeight * 2;
        goPanel3 = windowHeight * 3;

    $(window).resize(function(){

        goPanel1 = windowHeight;
        goPanel2 = windowHeight * 2;
        goPanel3 = windowHeight * 3;

        //alert(goPanel3);

    });
```

Thx,

Comment: Are you getting alert fired? in `resize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you are not getting the new window height after resizing, so it will give you the same old value over and over, you have to re-assign the value (get the value) from inside the event's function to get the new one and use it.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get new height after change
        goPanel1 = windowHeight;
        goPanel2 = windowHeight * 2;
        goPanel3 = windowHeight * 3;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        windowHeight = $(window).height(); // add this line
        goPanel1 = windowHeight;
        goPanel2 = windowHeight * 2;
        goPanel3 = windowHeight * 3;

        //alert(goPanel3);

    });
```

value to variable `windowHeight` was assigned out of `.resize` scope, and in `.resize` has previous value, but should have new value

Comment: Can you explain why windowHeight is out of scope? its a global var.

Comment: @KevinBowersox answer is reformulated. English is not my native language)