# Change variable value after window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, offset, var

I need change value offset after window resize.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var top_offset = $('header').height() - 1;
    $('header h1 a, nav li a').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - top_offset
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    //  dynamic margin-top for first section 'about'
    $("#about").css('margin-top', top_offset);
})
```

I tried:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    top_offset = $('header').height() - 1;
});
```

But it doesn't work. Still display older value.

Comment: Was your `window.resize` handler code within the scope of the `top_offset` variable defined within the `document.ready` block?

Comment: Tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443914/change-variable-values-on-window-resize?

Comment: Thanks. Your link resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to unbind the resize event before you bind it again. The code look should look something like this:

```
`$(window).unbind('resize', handleOffset)
 $(window).bind('resize', handleOffset) 
 function handleOffset(param) {
     //your code to reset offset
     //and yes you should look for the scope of top_offset variable
 }`
```