# Recalculate Radius on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, gsap

Here is a Simple truth.

Here is a guy at [Change variable values on window.resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443914/change-variable-values-on-window-resize) who has solved the Window resize update problem.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function(){
    windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get new height after change
```

});

However it does not work when i try to It in this manner by doing:

```
radius = Math.round( (($(window).width()) * 0.1302) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );


$(window).resize(function(){
    radius = Math.round( (($(window).width()) * 0.1302) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );
});
```

The calculation works as it is supposed to but it never refreshes the calculation on resize.

can you help me figure out why that is ?

Comment: Your code is uncomplete and not reproducable. `itemLength` is undefined. Also you are setting `radius` in the `resize()` function but don't apply it anywhere. All we can do is just guessing.

Comment: Also your code is faulty. I doubt it runs even the first time. `$(window).width()` does not need a `px` parameter. It returns the window's width in `px` already by default. Please look up: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Hi Mario! As said in the Question. the Calculation is correct. So please don't worry about ItemLength. But i Would be happy if you could explain further why I am not aplying the resize() anywhere?

Comment: Your code cannot run. `$(window).width('px')` returns an object an no number and therefore your calculation is `NaN`. It doesn't matter if you say "The calculation is correct". If you provide us faulty and incomplete code we cannot test, all we can do is guestimating. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have posted some more code. The code runs fine in my end. Only problem is it only performs the calculation once!

Comment: Check this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nuclearping/m5vuoeyy/ Your code does not run unmodified. Not with jQuery 1.x, nor with jQuery 2.x. Only if I remove the (nonsense) `px` parameter from `.width('px')` it works for both, `OnWindowReady` and `OnWindowResize`.

Comment: It makes no difference to remove ('px') you said it yourself it is set to px by default anyways. So if it makes you happy i will remove ('px') but it makes no difference.

Comment: No, I said the `px` parameter is nonsense. Because `.width('px')` returns an `Object` and you cannot do `[Object] * 0.1302`. See the jsFiddle link I posted. The first part (which is your code) returns `NaN`. The second code works in both cases, on load and on resize. Long story short: It only works if you remove the `px` paramter and use ith like `.width()` and thats the only error I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution turned out to involve more than I had expected. It was a line by Mario Werner that finally led me to the solution. After hours of flaming and indications that I was stupidity itself. Mario finaly gave the clue I needed. He said; "Outside the function's scope the radius variable is not available and thus will not be changed by this event."

This made me realize the problem and went on to do this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
$(document).ready( init )

function init()
{
    w = $(window);
    container = $( '#contentContainer' );
    carousel = $( '#carouselContainer' );
    item = $( '.carouselItem' );
    itemLength = $( '.carouselItem' ).length;
    fps = $('#fps');
    rY = 360 / itemLength;
    radius = Math.round( (($(window).width()) * 0.1302) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );


    // set container 3d props
    TweenMax.set(container, {perspective:600})
    TweenMax.set(carousel, {z:-(radius)})

    // create carousel item props

    for ( var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++ )
    {
        var $item = item.eq(i);
        var $block = $item.find('.carouselItemInner');

TweenMax.set($item, {rotationY:rY * i, z:radius, transformOrigin:"50% 50% " + -radius + "px"});

        animateIn( $item, $block )                      
    }

    // set mouse x and y props and looper ticker
    window.addEventListener( "mousemove", onMouseMove, false );
    ticker = setInterval( looper, 1000/60 );            
}
});
```

I simply placed the resize event outside the init function and copy pasted the exact same init function inside resize event. This works!

Thank you Mario!

Comment: No problem mate. :) Internet communication could be "rough" sometimes, since you only have text and therefore misunderstandings are a common issue. But you should honestly give credit to @paulol, since he first pointed out that you need to update the `radius` variable after you recalculated it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this whole part of the code that is in your init() function :

```
// set container 3d props
TweenMax.set(container, {perspective:600})
TweenMax.set(carousel, {z:-(radius)})

// create carousel item props

for ( var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++ )
{
    var $item = item.eq(i);
    var $block = $item.find('.carouselItemInner');

    TweenMax.set($item, {rotationY:rY * i, z:radius, transformOrigin:"50% 50% " + -radius + "px"});                     
}
```

must also be in the `$(window).resize` function. Else it won't update the items and the carousel, it will only update the variable `radius`.

Comment: No you really don't need any of the code you are asking for. I can't post that much code to you. We are talking about 400 lines of code. 

Here is another guy having the exact same problem. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443914/change-variable-values-on-window-resize

however his solution does not work in my case. which is really confusing.

Comment: Then can you send a link (if it's not private) to the page your creating ?

Comment: here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ac377gt6/1/ this won't run because you need TweenMax

Comment: I have rewritten my question because I think people have misunderstood what I am trying to do. Which is my fault ofcourse.

Comment: @Nulle The problem is that you seem to have some misunderstanding. You need to update your circle **DIRECTLY** after you updated the `radius` in the `$(window).resize(...)` function. Outside the function's scope the `radius` variable is not available and thus will not be changed by this event.

Comment: Ok now I see what you want to do. It's like a carousel of items arround a circle, isn't it ? I'll edit my answer and you'll tell me if it works

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me out Paulolol! No one should underestimate help from brilliant minds!

Comment: Thanks @Nulle . Cases like this one make me progress too. Because we're all always learning